# Game of Craps constantly looping

Tags: java, do-while

I am doing a task I was assigned in my Java programming course and I'm quite new to Java. Everything runs fine in the program as long as you don't trigger the do while statement, that's when it starts to loop out of control saying 'You rolled: 7 You lose'.

```
import java.util.Scanner; //Importing the java.util class Scanner

public class Craps {
    private Die die1;
    private Die die2;

    public Craps() {
        die1 = new Die();
        die2 = new Die();
    }

    private void rollDice() {
        die1.roll();
        die2.roll();
    }

    private int getSum() {
        return die1.getNumber() + die2.getNumber();
    }

    private int getSum2() {
        return die1.getNumber() + die2.getNumber();
    }

    public void playRound() {
        rollDice();
        int sum = getSum();
        int sum2 = getSum2();

        System.out.println("You rolled: " + sum);

        if (sum == 7 || sum == 11) {
            System.out.println("You Win");
        }

        if (sum == 2 || sum == 3 || sum == 12) {
            System.out.println("You Lose");
        } else if (sum == 4 || sum == 5 || sum == 6 || sum == 8 || sum == 9 || sum == 10) {
            System.out.println("Establishing the point, Re-rolling...");
            rollDice();
            sum2 = getSum2();
            do {
                if (sum2 == 7) {
                    System.out.println("You rolled: " + sum2);
                    System.out.println("You lose");
                }
                if (sum2 == sum) {
                    System.out.println("You rolled: " + sum2);
                    System.out.println("You win!!!");
                }
            }
            while (sum2 != sum || sum2 != 7);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Craps game = new Craps();

        System.out.println("Welcome to the game of Craps!!!");
        System.out.println("Rules: ");
        System.out.println("Rolling a 7 or 11 will win you the game");
        System.out.println("Subsequently rolling 2, 3, or 12 will lose you the game");
        System.out.println("If you roll a 4, 5, 6, 8, or 10 you will 'Establish the point'");
        System.out.println("Establishing the point allows you to set a new winning number and reroll");
        System.out.println("When you establish the point, the goal is to not roll a 7 and instead roll");
        System.out.println("the established number, rolling after establishing a point 7 now will");
        System.out.println("result in a loss");

        String ans = null;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            game.playRound();
            ans = scan.nextLine();
        }
        while (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));
    }
}
```

*EDIT* My Die class

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Die {
    private int number;
    private Random generator;

    public Die() {
        generator = new Random();
        roll();
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void roll() {
        number = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: So whats the question?

Comment: You are not re-rolling your die in the do/while loop so the numbers never change.

Comment: @MercifulGiraffe Thank you so much!!  I can't believe I missed that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum` and `sum2` are never updated inside your do/while loop, so once you get into the loop, you're never going to get out of it.

```
do {
    if (sum2 == 7) {
        System.out.println("You rolled: " + sum2);
        System.out.println("You lose");
    }
    if (sum2 == sum) {
        System.out.println("You rolled: " + sum2);
        System.out.println("You win!!!");
    }
}
while (sum2 != sum || sum2 != 7); // Condition never changes
```

Another nice pattern is taking advantage of `return` to short circuit:

```
while (true) {
    rollBabyRoll();
    if (getSum2() == 7) {
        // Log
        return;
    else if (getSum() == sum) {
        // Log
        return;
    }
}
```

**Bonus**

As another little tip, I don't know Craps at all, but you may want to think about using recursion instead.

```
private void reroll(int sum) {
    rollDice();
    int sum2 = getSum2();
    if (sum2 == 7) {
        // Do something
    else if (sum2 = sum) {
        // Do something
    } else {
        reroll(sum);
    }
}
```